# ViewPager2 Adapter is being called Twice

Tags: android, adapter, android-viewpager2

I am starting with Android java development and I am facing a issue on the ViewPager2 implementation.
On my app I have a ViewPager2 and I am inflate on it a layout which has a RecycleView.

The problem is, when I turn the ViewPager2 from page 0 to page 1, the adapter execulte onBindViewHolder twice, jumping from adapter position 0 to 1 and imediatelly from position 1 to 2. (ViewPager2 position stay on 1)

As I am populating the RecycleView with a Volley DB consult, this theard start only after the ViewPAger2 Adapter finish its works (after adapter execulte onBindViewHolder twice). So, only the ViewPager2 position 2 is populated (twice), ViewPager2 page 1 stay empty.

Thus, I kindly ask your help to avoid adapter execute onBindViewHolder twice once ViewPAger2 change. Or makes Volley executes its thread when the adapter position change from 0 to 1 and again when it change from 1 to 2.

Please help me since I have 5 days working around this problem without success.

See belwo my codes:

MY VIEWPAGER2 ADAPTER (Adapter_Department)

```
package br.com.portosaue.portosaueapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Adapter_Department extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter_Department.UserViewHolder> {

    Context mContext;

    private RecyclerView rcv_products;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    ViewPager2 vpg_productList;

    List<Department> departmentList;

    String Host_IP;
    String ProductComment;


    public MyAdapter(Context mContext, List<Department> departmentList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.departmentList = departmentList;
    }



    @NonNull
    @Override
    public UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        Host_IP = "192.168.0.100";
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.products_list, parent, false);
        return new UserViewHolder(view);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UserViewHolder holder, int position) {
        
        productsList(departmentList.get(position).getName());

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return departmentList.size();
    }


    public class UserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public UserViewHolder(@NonNull final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            rcv_products = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rcv_Products);
            vpg_productList = ((Activity) mContext).findViewById(R.id.vpg_Products);
        }
    }



    private void productsList(String department){

         //SELECTING URL
        String json_products;

        switch (department) {

            case "Salao":
                json_products = "http://" + Host_IP + "/getSalon.php";
                break;
            case "Cozinha":

                json_products = "http://" + Host_IP + "/getKitchen.php";
                break;

            case "Copa":

                json_products = "http://" + Host_IP + "/getDrink.php";
                break;

            case "Churrasqueira":

                json_products = "http://" + Host_IP + "/getBarbecue.php";
                break;

            case "Caixa":

                json_products = "http://" + Host_IP + "/getCash.php";
                break;
            default:
                json_products = "http://" + Host_IP + "/getProducts";
        }


        //VOLLEY / FETCH / JSONOBJECT
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, json_products,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            //converting the string to json array object
                            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);

                            ArrayList<Func_LoadProduct> loadproduct = new ArrayList<Func_LoadProduct>();
                            Func_LoadProduct p;
                            String ImagePath;

                            //traversing through all the object
                            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                                //getting product object from json array
                                JSONObject product = array.getJSONObject(i);


                                //adding the product to product list
                                ImagePath = "http://" + Host_IP + "/PS APP Images/" + product.getString("Imagem");

                                p = new Func_LoadProduct(product.getInt("ID"),
                                        product.getString("Nome"),
                                        product.getDouble("Preco"),
                                        ImagePath,
                                        "");
                                loadproduct.add(p);
                            }
                            
                            rcv_products=((Activity)mContext).findViewById(R.id.rcv_Products);
                            rcv_products.setHasFixedSize(true);
                            mLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(mContext);
                            mAdapter=new Adapter_Products(loadproduct);

                            rcv_products.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                            rcv_products.setAdapter(mAdapter);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });
        
        Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext).add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

VIEWPAGER2 CLASS (Products)

```
    package br.com.portosaue.portosaueapp;
    
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
    import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2;
    
    import com.android.volley.Request;
    import com.android.volley.Response;
    import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
    
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    
    
    public class Products extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    
        ViewPager2 vpg_products;
        List<Department> departmentList;
        Adapter_Department adapterDepartment;
        String TableNumb;
    
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_products);
    
            vpg_products = findViewById(R.id.vpg_Products);
    
    
            departmentList = new ArrayList<>();
            departmentList.add(new Department("Salon"));
            departmentList.add(new Department("Kitchen"));
            departmentList.add(new Department("Bar"));
    
            adapterDepartment = new Adapter_Department(this, departmentList);
            vpg_products.setAdapter(adapterDepartment);
        }
    
    }
```

VIEWPAGER2 LAYOUT (activity_departments.xml)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".Products"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    
        <include
            android:id="@+id/tbr_toobar"
            layout = "@layout/toolbar"/>
    
    
        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/vpg_Products"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tbr_toobar"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tbr_toobar"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
    
    
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

RECYCLEVIEW ADAPTER (Adapter_Products)

```
    package br.com.portosaue.portosaueapp;
    
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
    
    import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
    
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    
    
    
    public class Adapter_Products extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter_Products.MyViewHolder>{
    
    
        private ArrayList<Func_LoadProduct> mProductList;
    
        public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            public ImageView img_ProductImage;
            public TextView txv_ProductName;
            public TextView txv_ProductPrice;
            public TextView txv_ProductID;
    
    
            public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
    
                img_ProductImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imv_ProductImage);
                txv_ProductName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txv_ProductName);
                txv_ProductPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txv_ProductPrice);
                txv_ProductID = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txv_ProcutID);
    
            }
        }
    
        public Adapter_Products( ArrayList<Func_LoadProduct> productList){
    
            this.mProductList=productList;
        }
    
    
    
    
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.product_line, parent, false);
            MyViewHolder evh = new MyViewHolder(v);
    
            return evh;
        }
    
    
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    
    
            Func_LoadProduct currentItem = mProductList.get(position);
    
            Picasso.get().load(mProductList.get(position).getProductImageName()).into(holder.img_ProductImage);
    
            holder.txv_ProductName.setText(currentItem.getProductName());
            holder.txv_ProductPrice.setText("R$ " + Double.toString(currentItem.getProductPrice()));
            holder.txv_ProductID.setText("ID: " + Integer.toString(currentItem.getProductID()));
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
    
            return mProductList.size();
        }
    
    }
```

RECYCLEVIEW LAYOUT (product_list.xml)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
    
    
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rcv_Products"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />
    
    </RelativeLayout>
```

ITEMS CLASS (Func_LoadProduct)

```
    package br.com.portosaue.portosaueapp;
    
    
    public class Func_LoadProduct {
    
        private int ProductID;
        private String ProductName;
        private double ProductPrice;
        private String ProductImageName;
        private String ProductComment;
    
    
    
    
        public Func_LoadProduct(int productID, String productName, double productPrice, String productImageName, String productComment){
    
            this.ProductID = productID;
            this.ProductName = productName;
            this.ProductPrice = productPrice;
            this.ProductImageName = productImageName;
            this.ProductComment = productComment;
        }
    
        //SET
        public void setProductID(int productID) {
            this.ProductID = productID;
        }
    
        public void setProductName(String productName) {
            this.ProductName = productName;
        }
    
        public void setProductPrice(double productPrice) {
            this.ProductPrice = productPrice;
        }
    
        public void setProductImageName(String productImageName) { this.ProductImageName = productImageName; }
    
        public void setProductComment(String productComment) { this.ProductComment = productComment; }
    
    
        //GET
        public int getProductID() {
            return this.ProductID;
        }
    
        public String getProductName() {
            return this.ProductName;
        }
    
        public double getProductPrice() {
            return this.ProductPrice;
        }
    
        public String getProductImageName() { return this.ProductImageName; }
    
        public String getProductComment() { return this.ProductComment;  }
    }
```

ITEMS LAYOUT (product_line.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="4dp">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imv_ProductImage"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txv_ProductName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="64dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:text="Produto"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txv_ProductPrice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txv_ProductName"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:text="Valor"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txv_ProcutID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txv_ProductPrice"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="347dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="ID"
            android:textSize="15sp" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Ever heard of a [mcve]? StackOverflow is not for asking experts to debug you **WHOLE** code. Please show some effort and start to debug for yourself. If you then have an idea where the error is you can post the code and ask for help. Also take a [tour] and see [ask].

Comment: Friend, I am debuging the code since 5 days ago. I read all possible things to try to solve the problem by myself and I couldn't. I post my code not asking to a expert debug it, but just as reference if needed. Reading the post you can verify that my question was clear and straight to de point. I will be glad if someone can help me.

Comment: @Depizzol did you find any solution ?